# My createsjs preloader works well for previous version createjs but does not work for latest

Tags: createjs, easeljs

My preloader  works fine with previous version of createjs
but latest version of createjs  it does not work. so what the update needed ?

```
loader.onProgress = handleProgress;
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(22);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


    var progress = new createjs.Shape();
    var progressBellow = new createjs.Shape();
    var txt = new createjs.Text();


    progress.graphics.beginStroke("#280000").drawRect(115,112,400,40);
    progressBellow.graphics.beginStroke("#280000").drawRect(115,112,400,40);
txt.x = 150;
txt.y = 190;
txt.font = ("25px Verdana");
txt.color = ("#f11c35");
function handleProgress(event) {
    progress.graphics.clear();
    // Draw the progress bar
    progress.graphics.beginFill("#92ba17").drawRect(115,112,400*(event.loaded / event.total),40);
txt.text = ("Loading " + 100*(event.loaded / event.total) + "%");
}


stage.addChild(progress,progressBellow,txt);
stage.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onProgress` callback. Callbacks were removed a few versions ago (2013?) when bubbling events were added (the two methods aren't compatible).

Use an event instead:

```
loader.on("progress", handleProgress);
// OR
loader.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
```

Hope that solves your issue.